# Герметичный, но не совсем

Tags: терминология

Если что-то герметично, через него не проходит ничего, даже воздух. А как называется такой, через который не проходят никакие твёрдые частички, но проходит воздух?

Comment: Воздушный фильтр?

Comment: Даже не знаю...

Comment: В технике для разных по конструкции устройств используется термин "**полугерметичный**", но обычно это не связано со свойствами самого материала пропускать мелкие частицы. Это может быть холодильный компрессор, молочный сепаратор или нечто с клапаном, с возможностью разборки герм. соединения и т. п.

Comment: _Артём Луговой: Даже не знаю..._ === А чем Вам не нравится вариант, предложенный grizzly?

Comment: Герметичный стык (соединение). Плотно подогнанный стык (соединение).

Comment: @slava1947: нет, мне нравится, просто я не очень знаю, что это. И искал прилагательное другое.

Comment: _Артём Луговой: нет, мне нравится, просто я не очень знаю, что это. И искал прилагательное другое._ === Ну, если нужно прилагательное, попробуйте рассмотреть слово «пыленепроницаемый». Может, подойдёт?

Comment: @slava1947: спасибо! Хотелось вообще что-то попроще.

Answer (score 1):

Абсолютная герметичность недостижима и неконтролируема, поэтому герметичность следует рассматривать как понятие относительное и говорить лишь о ее степени.
Герметичность конструкции - основные понятия и термины: неплотность, поток через неплотность (течь), утечка, натекание. Здесь https://vunivere.ru/work61609/page3 об испытаниях на герметичность.
Определенную степень герметичности дает «притертая» стеклянная пробка, которая применяется для закупорки склянок с жидкостями, разъедающими резиновые и корковые пробки. Такие пробки обеспечивают наиболее плотную укупорку и применяются в основном при хранении жидких и порошкообразных веществ.
Кроме «притертой пробки» степень герметичности принято характеризовать многоэтажными словами типа «пылевлагозащищенный» (шкаф, аппарат, корпус часов) или «пылевзрывобезопасность».
Технарям удобнее использовать специальные обозначения, например: IP65 - Электротехническое оборудование со степенью защиты IP65 ( полная защита от пыли и защита от струй воды) может эксплуатироваться на улице в любых условиях.

Comment: Спасибо большое!